# ActiveRecord: How to grab record column value if I overwrite the getter method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `Users` table with 3 fields: `guest_email(string), email(string), and guest(boolean)`

I want to override the getting method for email so that if the user is a guest, it grabs the guest_email instead of the email.

How would I do this? This causes a stack overflow because it calls itself:

```
def email
  self.guest? ? self.guest_email : email
end
```

Inside the method, how would I grab the value of the email column of that particular record and bypass the getter method?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`read_attribute`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Read.html#method-i-read_attribute):

```
def email
  guest? ? guest_email : read_attribute(:email)
end
```

Alternatively, you can use `self[:attribute]` as pointed out by @Stefan:

```
def email
  guest? ? guest_email : self[:email]
end
```

Comment: `self[:email]` should work, too - it's an alias for `read_attribute`

Comment: Thank you @Stefan, both for pointing out the alternative syntax and updating the link.

Comment: thank you, I always forget how to do this